# How to run java code through Dockerfile using maven?

Tags: java, docker

We want to run our Java code through a Dockerfile by using Maven, but are not sure how to do this.
This is what we have written in the Dockerfile:
[image]

And this is how the output looks like when we build the dockerfile:
[image]

And this is how it looks like when we try to run it:
[image]

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Use Spotify maven docker plugin.

Comment: Provided Dockerfile includes references to `maven` and `openjdk` base images. But your building process is trying to download `nginx` base images. You are not building that Dockerfile but another one.

Comment: It looks like you've included three image files in the question.  I can't copy and paste that to try to reproduce it.  It looks like these might just be plain text; can you delete the images and replace them with the actual text of your Dockerfile and the output from your console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.